# How to Mask a Route with another Route in Laravel

Tags: php, wordpress, laravel-5

I want to redirect `www.myexample.com/back` when I call `www.myexample/blog/tree` without changing the url.
If I put the `www.myexample.com/back` in browser , it should load `www.myexample/blog/tree` with keeping the `www.myexample.com/back` in url bar.
In Laravel I tried

```
Route::get('/back',function(){
    return redirect('/blog/tree');
});
```

Please assume that the `www.myexample/blog/tree` is an actual wordpress URL

But it changes the url
Is there any way to achieve this ?

Comment: Use a mod_rewrite or equivalent for your web server

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use the Controller function of www.example.com/blog/free for route www.example.com/back. Two routes use the same function will return the same page. The redirect function will change the url, of course. For example:

```
Route::get('/blog/free','BlogController@free');
Route::get('/back','BlogController@free');
```

Comment: There is no Controller function, just want to call a wordpress blog

Answer (score 1):

You can create a view /back and use an iframe to load the blog inside it:
Something like:

```
Route::get('/back',function(){
    return view('back');
});
```

And then in the view `back.blade.php`  looks like

```
<html>
    <body>
        <iframe src="http://www.myexample/blog/tree"></iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```